# CoveoForSitecore how to override numberOfResults property

Tags: coveo

I am trying to override the `numberOfResults` property in Coveo Search UI before initializing, but doesn't seem to take affect. What could I be doing wrong?

```
Coveo.$('#@Model.Id').on("buildingQuery", function(e, args) {
 if(overrideNumberOfResults){
  args.queryBuilder.numberOfResults= 40;
  console.log(args.queryBuilder); //shows correct value of 40
 }
}).coveoForSitecore("init", CoveoForSitecore.componentsOptions);
```

Incorrect value when sent to service call. Shows 20 instead of 40.

[image]

Comment: Is this page using a pager or infinite scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Pager listens to the `buildingQuery` event ([according to this](https://developers.coveo.com/x/bYGfAQ)), it is probably the one overriding the query.

Try setting it in the `doneBuildingQuery` event instead.

Moreover, if you *don't* want a dynamic number of results and only want to set a result per page different from the OOTB offering, you can set it in the [Coveo Search component properties](https://developers.coveo.com/x/PgHvAQ) with the `Number of results per page` property in the `Paging` section. It can also [be set directly in the markup](https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/components/searchinterface.html#options.resultsperpage) of the `CoveoSearchInterface` using `data-results-per-page='10'`, but this approach that would require you to [duplicate the search component](https://developers.coveo.com/x/qADvAQ) since you are modifying the file and don't want your changes to be overridden.

Also, it might not be the case, but if you are trying to create your own [ResultPerPage component](https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/components/resultsperpage.html), Coveo for Sitecore started bundling one OOTB with the 4.0.450 version.

Simply add this tag in your CoveoSearchInterface:

```
<div class="CoveoResultsPerPage"></div>
```

Comment: I am seeing this error if I try to tap onto doneBuildingQuery event `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at CoveoForSitecore.min.js:1`. 
I do need to bring back dynamic number of results on the same result list.

Comment: Did you change something in your code? Only changing from `buildingQuery` to `doneBuildingQuery` should _never_ throw a `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. `Coveo.$('#@Model.Id')` is somehow `null` now and unrelated to the initial problem.

Comment: This is what I added `Coveo.$('#@Model.Id').on("doneBuildingQuery", function(e, args) { console.log("doneBuildingQuery");});`. I also have `buildingQuery` event somewhere on the page. Not sure if having both of these is conflicting and causing issue.

Comment: Actually I am seeing the `addEventListener` error no matter if I add `doneBuildingQuery` or not. So it seems like an error exists for a while not sure why. But one thing is sure only `buildingQuery` event is getting triggered. `newQuery` or `doneBuildingQuery` do not execute.

Comment: looks like if I attach `coveoForSitecore("init", CoveoForSitecore.componentsOptions)` to `buildingQuery` then `doneBuildingQuery` isnt called. For now I am going to attach the initialization to `doneBuildingQuery` instead.

Comment: Try storing `Coveo.$('#@Model.Id')` in a variable like so: `var searchInterface = Coveo.$('#@Model.Id');` and then calling it multiple times: `searchInterface.on("doneBuildingQuery", function() { ... });` `searchInterface.on("buildingQuery", function() { ... });` `searchInterface.coveoForSitecore("init", CoveoForSitecore.componentsOptions);`